# Inputfield for link to any contenttype in Bolt-cms

Tags: bolt-cms

is it possible to setup a field which links to a specific content of multiple content types?

So assuming there are 3 predefined contenttype CA, CB, CC. I would like to setup an input field, which allows to link to any content of the contenttypes CA, CB, CC.

Does anybody know how to do this or what section of bolt needs to be extended?

Thanks a lot!

---

I found the following three ways to link to other pages but they are always a link to one contenttype only.

By selectentry

```
selectentry:
        type: select
        values: entries/id
        postfix: "Select an entry"
        autocomplete: true
        sort: title
```

Single relation

```
relations:
    entries:
        multiple: false
        label: "Choose an entry"
        order: -id
        format: "{{ item.title|escape }} <span>(№ {{ item.id }})</span>"
        postfix: "By selecting an Entry, you're creating a bi-directional relationship to that Entry."
```

Multiple relations

```
relations:
    pages:
        multiple: true
        order: title
        label: Select zero or more pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is currently not possible to do in a clean way. You could add a few `type: select` fields, and then in your template use `{% if %}` statements to display the right thing.